# How to build a form field for a Join Table Entity

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony 3.0 I have 2 entities: Boat and Amenity. There needs to be a ManyToMany relationship between Boat and Amenity. I also need to be able to store the amount of Amenities a Boat has. Eg. A Boat can have 3 Kayaks. Therefor I have created to join table JoinBoatAmentity that stores: boat_id, amenity_id, amount.

My setup of entities looks like this:

```
Boat<OneToMany>JoinBoatAmentity<ManyToOne>Amenity
```

I have created this relationship according to this article http://future500.nl/articles/2013/09/doctrine-2-how-to-handle-join-tables-with-extra-columns/

I would like a section in the form that displays all the Amenities that are stored in the Amenity table, and that will have a field next to it displaying the amount this boat has, displaying 0 if it doesn't have any.
eg.:

```
[3] Kayak
[0] Surfboard
```

### EDIT -> (I added some example code below):

Currently my form builders look like this. This displays the Amenities of the boat that are in the JoinBoatAmenity table correctly, but it doesn't display the Amenities that the Boat doesn't have in the JoinBoatAmenity. I need the **form builder code** that also adds the rest of the existing Amenities that the boat doesn't have with a 0 value. Like the `[0] Surfboard`

```
#AdminBundle/Form/BoatType.php
namespace AdminBundle\Form;
class BoatType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('joinBoatAmenities', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => JoinBoatAmenityType::class,
            ])
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AdminBundle\Entity\Boat'
        ));
    }
}

#AdminBundle/Form/JoinBoatAmenityType.php
namespace AdminBundle\Form;
class JoinBoatAmenityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('amenity', TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'disabled' => true,
            ])
            ->add('amount', TextType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AdminBundle\Entity\JoinBoatAmenity'
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've show zero code, so it's really hard to help you. Hopefully you'll accept my answer, since I put some effort into it. On stackoverflow we expect some effort on your part...

First in your controller (which queries the boat to search for - I presume this is what you would do first) you should have a query builder, something like the following:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('b')
    ->from('AppBundle:Boat', 'b')
    ->where('b.boat_id = :boatID')
    ->setParameter('boatID', $boatToGetId)
    ->orderBy('b.boat_id', 'DESC');
$boat_results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Then later in that same controller (check the response for empty etc...), then render to a twig template:

```
return $this->render(
    'search/show_boats.html.twig',
    array('boats' => $boat_results,)
);
```

Then you can easily in twig templates do all kinds of things that you need with the entities. I'm using an example below, because you haven't told us anything about what you want to do.

```
{# app/Resources/views/search/show_boats.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    <h1>Boats Found:</h1>
    <p>Application Environment: {{ app.environment }}</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Boat name</th><th>Amenity</th>
        </tr>
        {% for b in boats %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ b.getName }}</td>
                <td>
                    {% for amen in b.getAmenities %}
                    {{ amen.getItem }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}{# b #}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Hopefully, this will help you get started. I used actual code for something similar I've done. Also, i'm not showing any of the form code above, because I don't know what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have added some more explanation and sample code. What I need is help with the form builder.